# Symfony form get user id

Tags: forms, symfony1

In order to filter the available options on one section of my web application, I would like to get the user object at the form object. I found some information about possible ways to do that (using `sfContext`, for instance) but some users discouraged this approach.

What is a possible manner to achieve my purpose?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way is to add some logic to BaseForm so you can use self::getValidUser(); without ever using sfContext, which is indeed generally not recommended.

Check this awesome blog post for more infos : http://prendreuncafe.com/blog/post/2010/02/17/User-Dependant-Forms-with-Symfony

Comment: Hi there!

Thanks for the help!

Best regards!